# Xamarin Forms Custom Renderer iOS UICollectionView scrolling in both directions / horizontal – vertical scrolling

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling, custom-renderer

Xamarin Forms Custom Renderer iOS UICollectionView scrolling in both directions / horizontal – vertical scrolling

**Intention:** Implementation of an interactive Grid which scroll horizontally and vertically .

**Problem:** 
The grid scrolls in both direction that much laggy. After scrolling with the finger you have to wait some seconds to see an reaction of the app.
We have implemented an UICollectionView in the same way in an native swift project, and it scrolls fluently. So I think the problem is rather the way of implementation than the rendering process.

With instruments I could find out that the CoreFoundation(RunLoops) cost the most of time(11s). So I guess its a threading problem.

Why I need to customize the UICollectionViewLayout to achieve horizontal scrolling? Because I need the ability to modify the width of single cells and other customizations too.
So the only way for scrolling in both direction I see, is to customize the UICollectionViewLayout.

**Implementation:**

*Xamarin.Forms Project:*

1. Create Custom Control (MyGrid) in Xamarin Forms, which extends from View Class:

   ```
    public class MyGrid : View
    {
       public MyGrid() : base()
       {
       }
    }
   ```
2. Use Custom Control ( MyGrid) in Xamarin Forms ContentPage):

   ```
   <ContentPage 
   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridDemo"
   x:Class="GridDemo.GridDemoPage">
     <ContentPage.Content>
      <local:MyGrid
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        BackgroundColor="White"/>
     </ContentPage.Content>
   </ContentPage>
   ```

*Xamarin.iOS Project:*

3. Implement Custom Renderer for MyGrid Class in iOS project:

   ```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyGrid), typeof(MyGridRenderer))]
   namespace GridDemo.iOS
   {
   public class MyGridRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyGrid, IOSGrid>
   {
       public MyGridRenderer()
       {
       }

       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyGrid> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);

           if (Control == null)
           {
               MyGrid myGrid = (MyGrid)e.NewElement;
               List<List<string>> values = myGrid.Source;

               var list = new List<CustomIOSGridCell>();
               var column = 0;
               var row = 0;
               var maxColumnLength = new int[myGrid.ColumnCount];
               for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.RowCount; i++)
               {

                   for (int j = 0; j < myGrid.ColumnCount; j++)
                   {
                       var array = values[i];
                       var stringLength = array.Aggregate("", (max, cur) => max.Length > cur.Length ? max : cur);
                       if (stringLength.Length > maxColumnLength[j])
                       {
                           maxColumnLength[j] = stringLength.Length;
                       }
                        list.Add(new CustomIOSGridCell(values[i][j));
                   }
               }

               var grid = new IOSGrid(this.Bounds, new IOSGridLayout(myGrid.ColumnCount, myGrid.RowCount, maxColumnLength));
               grid.AddValues(list, myGrid.ColumnCount, myGrid.RowCount);

               SetNativeControl(grid);
           }

           if (e.OldElement != null)
           {
               // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
           }

           if (e.NewElement != null)
           {
               // Configure the control and subscribe to event handlers
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```
4. Implement native control(iOSGrid), the corresponding Control to Custom Xamarin Forms Control (MyGrid):

   ```
       public class IOSGrid : UICollectionView
       {
         List<CustomIOSGridCell> values = new List<CustomIOSGridCell>();

         public IOSGrid(CGRect frame, IOSGridLayout collectionViewLayout) : base(frame, collectionViewLayout)
       {

         this.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(CustomCollectionViewCell), CustomCollectionViewCell.CellID);
         BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
       }

           public void AddValues(List<CustomIOSGridCell> values, int columncount, int rowCount)
           {
               this.values.AddRange(values);
               this.Source = new CustomCollectionSource(this.values, rowCount, columncount);
               this.ReloadData();
           }
       }
   ```
5. Implement Custom UICollectionViewLayout for IOSGrid(UICollectionView) to provide horizontal AND vertical scrolling

   ```
    public class IOSGridLayout : UICollectionViewLayout
    {
      private Timer timer;
      enum Direction { up, down ,leftRight, none }

      int columnsCount = 0;
      int rowCount = 0;

   CoreGraphics.CGSize[] itemsSize = null;
   CoreGraphics.CGSize contentSize = CoreGraphics.CGSize.Empty;
   int[] maxLength;

   public CGRect currentRect = CGRect.Empty;
   CGPoint currentCorner = new CGPoint(-1, -1);

   UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[,] itemAttributes;

   public IOSGridLayout(int columnsCount, int rowCount, int[] maxLength)
   {
       this.columnsCount = columnsCount;

       this.rowCount = rowCount;

       this.maxLength = maxLength;

       itemAttributes = new UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[rowCount, columnsCount];
   }

   public override void PrepareLayout()
   {

       if (CollectionView == null) return;
       var collectionView = CollectionView;
       if (collectionView.NumberOfSections() == 0) return;

       if (itemAttributes.Length != collectionView.NumberOfSections())
       {
           generateItemAttributes(collectionView);
           return;
       }

       for (int section = 0; section < collectionView.NumberOfSections(); section++)
       {
           for (int item = 0; item < collectionView.NumberOfItemsInSection(section); item++)
           {
               if (section != 0 && item != 0)
               {
                   continue;
               }

               var attributes = LayoutAttributesForItem(NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(item, section));                }
       }
   }

   public override CGSize CollectionViewContentSize
   {
       get { return contentSize; }
   }

   public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes LayoutAttributesForItem(NSIndexPath indexPath)
   {
       return itemAttributes[indexPath.Section, indexPath.Row];
   }

   public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect rect)
   {
       var attributes = new List<UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>();
       // calculate actual shown attributes

       return attributes.ToArray();
   }


   public override bool ShouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(CGRect newBounds)
   {
       return true;
   }

   private void generateItemAttributes(UICollectionView collectionView)
   {
       if (itemsSize?.Length != columnsCount)
       {
           CalculateItemSizes();
       }

       var column = 0;
       nfloat xOffset = 0;
       nfloat yOffset = 0;
       nfloat contentWidth = 0;


       itemAttributes = new UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[rowCount, columnsCount];

       var se = collectionView.NumberOfSections();
       for (int section = 0; section < rowCount; section++)
       {
           var sectionAttributes = new UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[columnsCount];

           for (int index = 0; index < columnsCount; index++)
           {
               var itemSize = itemsSize[index];
               var indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(index, section);
               var attributes = UIKit.UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.CreateForCell(indexPath);
               attributes.Frame = new CGRect(xOffset, yOffset, itemSize.Width, itemSize.Height).Integral();
               if (section == 0)
               {
                   var frame = attributes.Frame;
                   frame.Y = collectionView.ContentOffset.Y;
                   attributes.Frame = frame;
               }

               if (index == 0)
               {
                   var frame = attributes.Frame;
                   frame.X = collectionView.ContentOffset.X;
                   attributes.Frame = frame;
               }

               sectionAttributes[index]=attributes;

               xOffset += itemSize.Width;
               column += 1;

               if (column == columnsCount)
               {
                   if (xOffset > contentWidth)
                   {
                       contentWidth = xOffset;
                   }

                   column = 0;
                   xOffset = 0;
                   yOffset += itemSize.Height;
               }

           }
           for (int i = 0; i < sectionAttributes.Length; i++)
           {
               itemAttributes[section, i] = sectionAttributes[i];
           }
       }

       var attr = itemAttributes[rowCount-1,columnsCount-1];

       if (attr != null)
       {
           contentSize = new CGSize(contentWidth, attr.Frame.GetMaxY());
       }
   }

   private void CalculateItemSizes()
   {
       itemsSize = new CGSize[columnsCount];

       for (int index = 0; index < columnsCount; index++)
       {
           itemsSize[index] = SizeForItemWithColumnIndex(index);
       }
   }

   private CGSize SizeForItemWithColumnIndex(int index)
   {
       //  CollectionView.CellForItem()
       string text = "";
       for (int i = 0; i < maxLength[index]; i++)
       {
           text += "M";
       }

       NSString ma = new NSString(text);
       var size = ma.StringSize(UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(14));
       size.Height = 35;
       return size;
   }
   }
   ```
6. Implement Custom UICollectionViewSource for IOSGrid(UICollectionView):

   ```
   public class CustomCollectionSource : UICollectionViewSource
   {
         private readonly List<CustomIOSGridCell> values = new  List<CustomIOSGridCell>();

   private readonly int rowCount = 0;

   private readonly int columnCount = 0;

   public CustomCollectionSource(List<CustomIOSGridCell> values, int rowCount, int columnCount)
   {
       this.values = values;
       this.rowCount = rowCount;
       this.columnCount = columnCount;
   }

   public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
   {
       return rowCount;
   }

   public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
   {
       return columnCount;
   }

   public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
   {
       var cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(CustomCollectionViewCell.CellID, indexPath);
       cell.UpdateCell(values[indexPath.Row].Text);

       return cell;
   }
   }
   ```
7. Implement Custom UICollectionViewCell for IOSGrid(UICollectionView):

   ```
   public class CustomCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
       {
          public UILabel mainLabel;
          public static NSString CellID = new  NSString("customCollectionCell");

   [Export("initWithFrame:")]
   public CustomCollectionViewCell(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
   {
       // Default
       ContentView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;
       ContentView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.0f;
       ContentView.Layer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White.CGColor;

       mainLabel = new UILabel();

       ContentView.AddSubview( mainLabel );
   }

   public void UpdateCell(string text)
   {
       mainLabel.Text = text;
       mainLabel.Frame = new CGRect(5, 5, ContentView.Bounds.Width, 26);
   }
   }
   ```