# Can't find GridViewLayout documentation

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, grid

I'm looking for the documentation for `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.GridViewLayout` and/or `UICollectionViewLayout`. I need to create a grid using native iOS layout managers but I can't find anything. I want to make [This Layout](https://github.com/Jakar510/Jakar.SettingsView/blob/master/src/SettingsView.Droid/Resources/layout/CellLayout.axml) in iOS.

I found [this SO anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18268926/9530917)  but the link is dead. As well as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928246/xamarin-forms-custom-renderer-ios-uicollectionview-scrolling-in-both-directions) but I want it in a set layout not variable (the `UICollectionViewSource`)

For `UICollectionViewLayout` i found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/uicollectionview).

Comment: do you want to achieve this [effect](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6554)?

Comment: No. want a static grid that auto sizes to fill its container (the cell).

Comment: about UICollectionViewLayout , [this thread](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6554), someone has feedback this problem at github.